# WARNING: You are currently running a version of TypeScript which is not officially supported by @typescript-eslint/typescript-estree

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ubuntu, warnings, react-scripts

Hello there I am getting some error in my terminal and its say i need to use 4.4.0 version and my current version is ...

In my project my current typescript version is given below,

```
    "typescript": "^4.4.2",
    "typedoc": "^0.21.8",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.4",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.29.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.29.3",
```

Moreover, when I am trying to run **npm run dev** commands or **npx eslint .** is error are showing me which is given below,

```
    =============

   WARNING: You are currently running a version of TypeScript which is not 
   officially supported by @typescript-eslint/typescript-estree.

    You may find that it works just fine, or you may not.

   SUPPORTED TYPESCRIPT VERSIONS: >=3.3.1 <4.4.0

   YOUR TYPESCRIPT VERSION: 4.4.2

     Please only submit bug reports when using the officially supported 
    version.

    =============
```

How can i fix this issue and I have done a lot of research in google but nothing is working. It would be great help for me.

Answer (score 42):

I was struggling with the same warning. Solved it by updating eslint and related packages to the latest by running:

`npm i eslint@latest @typescript-eslint/parser@latest @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@latest --save`

Now, I have the following versions in my **package.json** and I am not receiving the warning anymore

```
"eslint": "^8.38.0",
"eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
"eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.0",
"typescript": "^5.0.4"
```

Comment: not necessarily install latest, but go to your package.json and ensure to give enough slack for an update ( eg, change `"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.25.0",` => `"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5" `), then `npm update @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin` etc.

Answer (score 15):

I wouldn't downgrade my Typescript, as you will miss out on newer TS features - I would find a way to update `@typescript-eslint/typescript-estree`.

You might not have this installed directly and this might be a dependancy of another package, `@typescript-eslint/experimental-utils` which is dependancy of `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin` for instance, so track down the parent package in your `yarn.lock / package.lock` file and bump it, as a result it should bump `@typescript-eslint/typescript-estree` too.

Comment: I am having the same issue. Can you provide a bit more clarity on what you mean by 'track down the parent package ... and bump it" ? I've never actually manually edited a lock file before. This is my pnpm-lock.yaml file: https://github.com/currenthandle/react-road-to-enterprise/blob/main/pnpm-lock.yaml

Comment: Hm, your case seems a bit different than mine - so I had 3 packages which used different versions of `@typescript-eslint/typescript-estree`, one of those packages was using `@typescript-eslint/typescript-estree@1.4.0`, the other two were using `5.0.x` and `4.x.x`. So when I updated the first package, this resulted updating the typescript-estree dependancy and the warning message disappeared.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the issue was an outdated `eslint-config-next`. Make sure to update that, too, on top of updating `@typescript-eslint/parser` and `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using yarn, so I increased the version of `@typescript-eslint/typescript-estree` using `resolutions` in the package.json, and the warning disappeared. npm seems to be able to use `overrides`.

package.json

```
  "resolutions": {
    "@typescript-eslint/typescript-estree": "^5.59.2"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the version of your typescript to 5.1.0 in both package.json and package.lock.json. You can run this command afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe the eslint package is out-of-dated, if you use pnpm like me. Just run `pnpm update` to update all packages (or you can edit version in package.json for what version you need, and then run `pnpm install`).

Answer (score -1):

For the future. You only need to fix the typescript version to fixed. Maybe the latest versions of @typescript-eslint... don't support your TS version.

Answer (score -1):

Try deleting the ***yarn.log*** file and re-running the ***npm install***. This works for me.

Answer (score -8):

Try using a typescript version between >=3.3.1 <4.4.0.
[Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript) you have the list of typescript versions available.

After changing the version, remove **node_modules** folder and **package-lock.json** file. Then execute `npm install`

Comment: Thank you very much I had already resolve this issue and I had added relevant supported version which was 4.3.2 of typescript and everything is working fine. Thanks once again for your help.